# setlabel in Qlabel will assign a variable in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I'm still starting out with PyQt with QtDesigner using eric4 (and still studying python as a whole).

Anyway, as I've designed in a GUI using QtDesigner I've just made a Qlabel as a placeholder which is intended to update with the latest ID that has access to a SQLite database which I'm building. I want it to setlabel to change to the next slot available in ID primary key but I honestly don't know how.

I've tried to change the UI compiled form as I noticed that it is this line:

```
self.ID_Number.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog","IDLabel", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

that sets the label of the supposed ID_Number which would communicate with the SQLite. But I always get a compiling error when I changed "IDLabel" to a variable. I've checked that it is supposed to be a constant but would it be possible that it can be a variable instead? Or am I doing wrong to use a QLabel in QtDesigner and I should use something else?

Any help in solving the wall I'm trying break is very much appreciated *bows deeply*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `translate` function call is used for multi-language support. You can remove it in this case and simplify the code to the following.

```
self.ID_Number.setText(somePythonStringVariable)
```

Comment: Thanks! I just did some testing by making a variable like - label = "1" - and assigned it to setText and it worked. So in other words, I need to convert the primary key ID from the sqlite to string first then it should display the ID. Thanks again for the help :D